# Change Xcode Playground Font for comments/description

Tags: xcode, markup, swift-playground

How can I change the font of "Topline" below to a e.g. smaller font, colored what ever in a Playground Page?

```
import Foundation
//: # Topline
var greeting = "Hello, playground"

//: [Next](@next)
```

The above code in a playground page will be rendered as

[image: playgroundOutput]

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that in Markdown, it's a header, `next` is a link, that's why it's blue.

Comment: Right, so where to change the default/presets font (-styles) for each of markdown format/text in Xcode, e.g. for  # Topline?